# Extracting information from a table on a website using python, LXML & XPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, xpath, lxml

I managed after lots of hard work to extract some information that i needed from a table from this website:

http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57108

From the table "Kommande Matcher"(second table) I managed to extract the date and the team names.

But now i am totally stuck trying to extract from the first table:

- The first column "Lag"
- The second column "S"
- 6h column "GM-IM"
- last column "P"

Any ideas? , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just did it:

```
from io import BytesIO
import urllib2 as net
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html    

request = net.Request("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57108")
response = net.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()

collected = [] #list-tuple of [(col1, col2...), (col1, col2...)]
dom = lxml.html.parse(BytesIO(data))
#all table rows    
xpatheval = etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator(dom)
rows = xpatheval('//div[@id="content-primary"]/table[1]/tbody/tr')

for row in rows:
    columns = row.findall("td")
    collected.append((
        columns[0].find("a").text.encode("utf8"), # Lag
        columns[1].text, # S
        columns[5].text, # GM-IM
        columns[7].text, # P - last column
    ))

for i in collected: print i
```

### [image]

You could to pass URL in lxml.html.parse() directly rather than call urllib2. Also, you'd grab target table by class attribute, like this:

```
# new version
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html    

collected = [] #list-tuple of [(col1, col2...), (col1, col2...)]
dom = lxml.html.parse("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57108")
#all table rows
xpatheval = etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator(dom)
rows = xpatheval("""//div[@id="content-primary"]/table[
    contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " clTblStandings ")]/tbody/tr""")

for row in rows:
    columns = row.findall("td")
    collected.append((
        columns[0].find("a").text.encode("utf8"), # Lag
        columns[1].text, # S
        columns[5].text, # GM-IM
        columns[7].text, # P - last column
    ))

for i in collected: print i
```

Comment: It worked like a charm thank you! What did you mean with your P.S i did not get it?

Comment: One quick question. I see that you used table[1] in rows. What i think is that the websites tables dynamically change from 2 tables to 3 tables meaning that table can maybe be table 2 or 1. Is there a way to fix that so regarding which table it is it will still find the correct table

Comment: @hamzah Maybe! If "table[1]" always is on first position on DOM, it's ok. However, if the target table appears on DOM in a different order than 1, so you could to get target table by class attribute: table[@class="clTblStandings"] instead table[1].  I've edited my anwser. Take a look!

Comment: Hey! Could you possible look at this post to. I see that its the same website maybe you can help here to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595105/extract-information-from-website-using-xpath-python @felipsmartins