# Extract information from website using Xpath, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

Trying to extract some useful information from a website. I came a bit now im stuck and in need of your help!

I need the information from this table

http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=scorers&ftid=57700

I wrote this code and i got the information that i wanted:

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.etree import XPath

url = ("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=scorers&ftid=57700")

rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr")
name_xpath = XPath("td[1]//text()")
team_xpath = XPath("td[2]//text()")

league_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/h1//text()")


html = lxml.html.parse(url)

divName = league_xpath(html)[0]

for id,row in enumerate(rows_xpath(html)):
    scorername = name_xpath(row)[0]
    team = team_xpath(row)[0]
    print scorername, team


print divName
```

I get this error

```
    scorername = name_xpath(row)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do understand why i get the error. What i really need help with is that i only need the first 12 rows. This is what the extract should do in these three possible scenarios:

If there are less than 12 rows: Take all the rows except THE LAST ROW.

If there are 12 rows: same as above..

If there are more than 12 rows: Simply take the first 12 rows.

How can i can i do this?

**EDIT1**

It is not a duplicate. Sure it is the same site. But i have already done what that guy wanted to which was to get all the values from the row. Which i can already do. I don't need the last row and i dont want it to extract more than 12 rows if there is..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting information from a table on a website using python, LXML & XPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448934/extracting-information-from-a-table-on-a-website-using-python-lxml-xpath)

Comment: @felipsmartins its not a duplicate, check my edit

Comment: Ok, I'll put my answer soon.

Comment: Perfect, anxious to see how you solve it :D @felipsmartins

Comment: I've just poested my answear. Take a look it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is it what you want:

```
#coding: utf-8
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html

collected = [] #list-tuple of [(col1, col2...), (col1, col2...)]
dom = lxml.html.parse("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=scorers&ftid=57700")
#all table rows
xpatheval = etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator(dom)
rows = xpatheval('//div[@id="content-primary"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr')
# If there are less than 12 rows (or <=12): Take all the rows except the last.
if len(rows) <= 12:
    rows.pop() 
else:
    # If there are more than 12 rows: Simply take the first 12 rows.
    rows = rows[0:12]

for row in rows:
    # all columns of current table row (Spelare, Lag, Mal, straffmal)
    columns = row.findall("td")
    # pick textual data from each <td>
    collected.append([column.text for column in columns])

for i in collected: print i
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect, I used the techniques you used to my own code. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the rows you need based on what you described in your post. This is just the logic based on concept that `rows` is a list, you have to incorporate this into your code as needed.

```
if len(rows) <=12:
    print rows[0:-1]
elif len(rows) > 12:
    print rows[0:12]
```

Comment: But it is just printing out elements? I don't see how i can access the individual elements like i do in my code?

Comment: @AppDev I put print there but but you can do anything you need to with this. This answer your question in your post: "if there are less than 12 rows: Take all the rows except THE LAST ROW. If there are 12 rows: same as above..If there are more than 12 rows: Simply take the first 12 rows. How can I do this?"

Comment: @AppDev instead of `print` you can just have a variable like `x` like so: `x = rows[0:-1]` or `x = rows[0:12]` then you can iterate through `x` and access the individual elements